# How to do string.Split(''')?

Tags: c#

I need to split a string with the character `'` using string.Split()
However, the `'` character is used in the string.Split()

For example:

```
string.Split(''')
```

but that gives a syntax error.
I have tried using the `@` symbol to represent a literal string, but that does not work either.

```
string.Split(@''')
```

Comment: do you want to split by single quote or double quotes?

Comment: I want to use a single quote

Comment: `.Split(new char[] { '\''})`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. :)

Comment: This doesn't relate to WinForms so I've removed that tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-160#escape-sequences-1) before single quote `.Split('\'')`, like

```
var str = "Hell'o'Wo'rl'd";
var output = str.Split('\''); //["Hell", "o", "Wo", "rl", "d"]
```

[.NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/suQBV8)